Validate the pattern of an xml file's name
i working on a robot framework project. The target of the test is to evaluate if the xml file name respect the specific pattern.
First attempt:
*** Variables ***
${FILENAME}    222222_XT211-D(SM211)_Scenario_SetFrameCounter_result_6157_ok_02112024-172720.xml
${PATTERN}     ^\d{6}_XT\d{3}-D\(SM\d{3}\)_Scenario_SetFrameCounter_result_\d{4}_ok_\d{8}-\d{6}\.xml$

*** Test Cases ***
Validate Xml Filename Structure
    Should Match     ${FILENAME}    ${PATTERN}

Second attempt:
*** Variables ***
${FILENAME}    222222_XT211-D(SM211)_Scenario_SetFrameCounter_result_6157_ok_02112024-172720.xml
${PATTERN}     ^\d{6}_XT\d{3}-D\(SM\d{3}\)_Scenario_SetFrameCounter_result_\d{4}_ok_\d{8}-\d{6}\.xml$

*** Test Cases ***
Validate Xml Filename Structure
    Should Match Rexep     ${FILENAME}    ${PATTERN}

But as result, it always fails and i don't know exactly where's the fail.:
This is what i got as result.
'222222_XT211-D(SM211)_Scenario_SetFrameCounter_result_6157_ok_02112024-172720.xml' does not match '^d{6}_XTd{3}-D(SMd{3})_Scenario_SetFrameCounter_result_d{4}_ok_d{8}-d{6}.xml$'

Why is this tagged for Python?

i'm failing to see how the first and second attempts are different

@Nabil, help us helping you by providing a bit more context for your question: What programming language are you using (Python?), share the relevant section of your code, what have you tried so far to resolve the issue? For example, have you tested your regex e.g. on regex101?

@SIGHUP Robotframework uses python's re engine under the hood is the only reason why i would understand python tag.

@rasjani But there is no Python code so it's superfluous

You should use double backslashes because Robot Framework itself is using backslashes to escape test data.
Link to documentation
So in you case ${PATTERN} would be:
*** Variables ***
${PATTERN}     ^\\d{6}_XT\\d{3}-D\\(SM\\d{3}\\)_Scenario_SetFrameCounter_result_\\d{4}_ok_\\d{8}-\\d{6}\\.xml$


it's working with your proposed solution. Thanks.
